# Is there an Infura or similar node service compatible with eosjs? For testnet/mainnet? Or, is starting your own node the way to go?

Tags: eosjs, testnet

Are there any public api nodes for EOS? I.e. API key rate limited, etc

I'd also appreciate a post on using the EOS testnet the first time. I can't find anything in Google search results about EOS, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your eosjs or cleos with public api nodes and there is not any api key needed it's also not rate limited.

For test public api nodes you can directly ping [here](https://monitor.jungletestnet.io/#apiendpoints) and you will get list of api nodes.

For mainnet please refer this official [documentation](https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/) by eosio.